# Mount not working with systemd (working with /etc/fstab)

Tags: mount, systemd, fstab, system

I have a working line in /etc/fstab for mounting a remote samba server

```
//192.168.1.11/wind  /media/fixe/wind         cifs noauto,user,username=XXX,password=YYY,rw  0 0
```

But **I would now use automount with systemd** (I have other mounting with systemd to NAS synology who are working).

So I tried in `mnt-fixe-wind.mount` :

```
meloli@Asus-A17:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo nano mnt-fixe-wind.mount 


[Unit]
Description = My Share mount
Requires = dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service
After = network-online.target
Wants = network-online.target

[Mount]
What = //192.168.1.11/wind
Where = /mnt/fixe/wind
Options = username=XXX,password=YYY,rw
Type = cifs
TimeoutSec = 30

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

When trying `sudo systemctl start mnt-fixe-wind.mount` the output is

```
    meloli@Asus-A17:/etc/systemd/system$ journalctl -xe                               
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) NetworkManager-dispatcher.service a commencé à démarrer.
janv. 28 08:59:39 Asus-A17 mount[15436]: mount error(22): Invalid argument
janv. 28 08:59:39 Asus-A17 mount[15436]: Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
janv. 28 08:59:39 Asus-A17 systemd[1]: mnt-fixe.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An n/a= process belonging to unit mnt-fixe.mount has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 32.
janv. 28 08:59:39 Asus-A17 systemd[1]: mnt-fixe.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mnt-fixe.mount has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
janv. 28 08:59:39 Asus-A17 systemd[1]: Failed to mount My Share mount.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) mnt-fixe.mount a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) mnt-fixe.mount a échoué, avec le résultat failed.
janv. 28 08:59:39 Asus-A17 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for My Share mount.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) mnt-fixe-wind.mount a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) mnt-fixe-wind.mount a échoué, avec le résultat dependency.
janv. 28 08:59:39 Asus-A17 systemd[1]: mnt-fixe-wind.mount: Job mnt-fixe-wind.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
janv. 28 08:59:39 Asus-A17 kernel: CIFS: VFS: Malformed UNC in devname
janv. 28 08:59:39 Asus-A17 sudo[15431]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
janv. 28 08:59:39 Asus-A17 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) NetworkManager-dispatcher.service a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) NetworkManager-dispatcher.service a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
```

Mountpoint is existing

```
meloli@Asus-A17:/etc/systemd/system$ cd /mnt/fixe/wind/
meloli@Asus-A17:/mnt/fixe/wind$
```

What is wrong ? Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try this: add another option: `vers=1.0` or `vers=2.0` (or any of the versions mentioned in `man mount.cifs`)?

Comment: I tried with`vers=1.0`, `vers=2.0`,`vers=2.1` and `vers=3.0`  and same error

Comment: Does the folder under /mnt exist?

Comment: Yes `meloli@Asus-A17:~$ cd /mnt/fixe/wind/` output `meloli@Asus-A17:/mnt/fixe/wind$`

Comment: I edit the log output because the output seems to be different today